# Check whether prime or not in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, primes

I'm trying to learn Prolog and I've found an example where I need to implement a program to check whether a number is prime or not with a single predicate.

The logic I'm trying to follow is to make a recursive rule to divide by all the number less than that predicate till it reaches the base case which is either `X>2` because `0` and `1` aren't primes and divisible by itself

My code till now is :

```
isPrime(2).
isPrime(X):-
    X>2, %0,1 aren't primes
    1 is mod(X,2),
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Must you use a _single_ predicate to achieve this? It's very easy with two.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a single predicate :)

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy provided you don't care about efficiency.

```
isPrime(X) :-
  X > 1,
  succ(X0, X),
  \+ (between(2, X0, N), 0 is X mod N).
```

:)

Comment: Instead of `succ(X0, X)` you could use `X0 is truncate(sqrt(X))` :)

Comment: @lurker: Your suggestion does not work with very large integers: sqrt gives a float.

Comment: @false doesn't `truncate` take care of that? Or are there some extra large integer types that work with `sqrt` but which `truncate` would yield a "normal" integer that doesn't fit the type for `truncate`?

Comment: @lurker: By very large I meant so large that the square root can no longer be represented exactly. Say X is 7^7^3

Comment: @false interesting. Playing with it at the Prolog prompt I see that `truncate` (and `floor`, etc) work for integers up to `2**27` but then doesn't give correct results for `2**28` and up. I was a little surprised by that, but haven't really dug into the internal representations to explain it.